# Swift - How to assign URLSession.dataTask(with:) decoded data to an external variable?

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, urlsession

I am exploring APIs and practicing with a simple stock ticker retrieval app. I can successfully pull JSON data using a custom queried URL. I have the the object model set up correctly:

```
    struct TCKR: Decodable {
        let symbol: String
        let delayedPrice: Double?
        let iexRealtimePrice: Double
        ...
    }
```

I also have an API Request Handler struct that handles the ticker symbol string, API token, and URL generation

```
    struct IEXCloudRequest {
        var tckr: TCKR! //I swear I'll provide it at some point 

        let strTckr: String
        let myToken = "?token=lqj34poiruadosfnp39u2rkndaslkfnmxnip32ur"

        var reqURL: URL {
            return URL(string: "blah" + strTckr + myToken)!
        }
    }
```

I am in SwiftUI and want to use the tckr object created by my API Request Handler to display the properties. This is how I would like to handle the object model.

```
    //ContentView.swift

    struct ContentView: View {
        let tckr: TCKR = IEXCloudRequest("AAPL").tckr

        var body: some View {
            Text(tckr.symbol)
        }
    }
```

The problem is I don't know how to extract the decoded tckr from JSONDecoder and use it globally. The current method I'm using is:

```
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: self.reqURL { data, response, error in
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let tckrShell = try JSONDecoder().decode(TCKR.self, from: data)
                print("object creation success for ticker: \(String(describing: tckrShell!.symbol))")
                //I consistently print from this block so my API Calls and data decoding are working
            } catch {
                print("we have an E")
                print(error)

            }
        } else {
            print("data from URL returned nil")

        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

Whenever I try to assign the `tckrShell` variable externally, I'm getting an error about how I can't assign mutating self variables when using @escaping completion handlers and thus can't use my `TCKR` object 'globally'. Please gods of Swift, help a brother out.

Answer (score 0):

For assign `tckrShell` to an external variable you need completion block in the fetch request method. you can handle it something like this :

```swift
fund doNetworkCall(Your input, completionBlock: @escaping (TCKR) -> Void)  {
   let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: self.reqURL { data, response, error in
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let tckrShell = try JSONDecoder().decode(TCKR.self, from: data)
                completionBlock(tckShell)
                return
                print("object creation success for ticker: \(String(describing: tckrShell!.symbol))")
                //I consistently print from this block so my API Calls and data decoding are working
            } catch {
                print("we have an E")
                print(error)
                return
            }
        } else {
            print("data from URL returned nil")

        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the setup wrong. You cant change strict properties from a closure. If you need to do so, use a class instead of struct

Refactored your code into MVVM:

```
    struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(viewModel.ticker?.delayedPrice ?? 0.0)")
    }
}

class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {

    var ticker: TCKR? = nil {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    var apiService: ApiService?

    init(apiService: ApiService = ApiService()) {
        self.apiService = apiService
        getApiCount()
    }

    var objectWillChange: ObservableObjectPublisher = ObservableObjectPublisher()

    func getApiCount() {
        apiService?.getTheList(completion: { [weak self] (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.ticker = response
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
    }
}



struct TCKR: Decodable {
    let symbol: String
    let delayedPrice: Double?
    let iexRealtimePrice: Double

}

struct IEXCloudRequest {

    let strTckr: String
    let myToken = "?token=lqj34poiruadosfnp39u2rkndaslkfnmxnip32ur"

    var reqURL: URL {
        return URL(string: "blah" + strTckr + myToken)!
    }
}

struct ApiService {

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let request: IEXCloudRequest

    init(request: IEXCloudRequest = IEXCloudRequest(strTckr: "AAPL")) {
        self.request = request
    }

    func getTheList(completion: @escaping (Result<TCKR, Error>) -> Void) {

        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request.reqURL) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let responseData = data else {
                return
            }
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
            let response = try jsonDecoder.decode(TCKR.self, from: responseData)
                completion(.success(response))
            } catch {
                print(error)
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }

}


enum Result<T, E: Error> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(E)
}
```

Comment: You need to import Combine into your viewmodel and View files